# Android design guidelines about left aligning action bar

Tags: android, guidelines

I am trying to find out if it is an Android design guideline to left align the text in the action bar. My search has gotten me two things. Firstly a way to center it, by creating a custom view, which seems like a hack and has been called that once or twice. It also feels dirty. Secondly another question related to this here on stackexchange claiming that it is indeed against android guidelines [link here but i am not allowed to add a comment](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/50921/android-pattern-of-left-aligning-in-action-bar).

> The design guideline for Android action bars is to left align the text or branding of the app, as opposed to center alignment in iOS.

Other article also seem to assume this, [like this one](http://www.kinvey.com/blog/2765/ios-and-android-design-guidelines-cheat-sheet)

However when I try to look up this claim in official documents, [like here](https://developer.android.com/design/patterns/actionbar.html), I am unable to find this.

So is it, or is it not Android policy to keep your action bar left aligned?

Comment: It would be useful to add quotes from the linked sites just in case the links don't remain active.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess as per the [new material design guidelines](http://www.google.com/design/spec/layout/structure.html#structure-app-bar), they even some dimensions about the same.

[image]

I hope you were looking for the same.

Comment: It just assigns a place where the title should be, nothing about the alignment of the text.

Comment: Alignment with respect to what?

Comment: Center aligning the Title.

Comment: That 72 is from where your title starts. That's left aligned. Having it centre aligned is how iOS does it. That is entirely a different pattern. They have menus divided at both sides of title.